# Return success on delete in JQuery FileUpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-events

I am using [blueimp's Jquery file upload plugin](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). For adding files, there are a host of different callbacks. For example:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
```

I would like to bind to a callback that tells me if a file has been deleted successfully, but I have searched the documentation and can't find anything that looks like it does this. Anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Update:
I should say that the above code only returns for UPLOADING a file. No event is returned for deleting a file. This is what I want to try and implement into bluimp's source code.

Source code for callbacks is here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js

Comment: The state of your downloaded file is known on the server. So in your `data` variable (it is the json response of your server), you can pass any information and for example, if your file has been deleted successfully.

Comment: but the problem is that i then need to implement the handler into the file upload source. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: It depends on what you have transmitted from the server (in the `data`variable : have you debugged it?). But let's say, you have some object like this : `data : { kind : "error", message : "Deletion failed" }`, in your callback function you will have to test over `data.kind` : `if (data.kind === "error") alert(data.message);`.

Comment: Im not sure I am following - the problem is that even if I send the data as you have described, there is no callback function to handle it. Maybe my knowledge has some gaps. Would you be able to add some more detail in an answer? - that would be super helpful.

Comment: have added the source code which defines the callback functions. If i could change the code in there to respond to a deletion that would work i think

Comment: The callback function is the code `function (e, data) {/* ... */}`. But you can also decouple the implementation like this : `$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', callbackfunc); function callbackfunc(e, data) { /* your code, like : if (data.kind === "error") alert(data.message); */ }`.

Comment: ah i see! (I can see there are some gaps in my understanding). Do you want to submit that as an answer? I'll give it a go now.

Comment: Ok, I have submitted an answer with one or 2 more remarks. Hope this has helped you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the previous comments, the callback function is the function that will handle the data received from the server via the event `fileuploaddone`. Thus, you will have such code :

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', callbackfunc); 

// Your callback function
function callbackfunc(e, data) { 
    /* your code, like : if (data.kind === "error") alert(data.message); */ 
}
```

But you can shorten it via an anonymous function :

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* your code, like : if (data.kind === "error") alert(data.message); */})
```

---

**EDIT**

For deletion, the callback can be bound with event `fileuploaddestroy` (see this page : [BlueImp options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)).

Comment: ah but that's what i was trying to tell you, fileuploaddone is only called when uploading a file. NO EVENT is called when deleting a file. That's why I said there is no way for me to handle any data from deleting a file.

Comment: Oh ok, I haven't correctly understand your problem. For a deletion, you should use `fileuploaddestroy` (see at the bottom of this page : [BlueImp options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options), there is a part named "Additional Callback Options for the UI version" and in particular "destroy").

Comment: Ah yes! That's exactly what I wanted! Not sure how I missed it - the documentation is a bit all over the place though. If you update your answer, I'll mark it has correct. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: fileuploaddestroy  event is called  even  before the delete request is called or made to the server.So i think there is no success delete callback here.If there is any work around mention a example.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody still looking for this, I found solution by changing "removeNode" function declarations in "destroy" function in jquery.fileupload-ui.js file to:

```
removeNode = function (d) {
    that._transition(data.context).done(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        that._trigger('destroyed', e, d);
    });
};
```

then just add event for "fileuploaddestroyed" and data will contain server response instead of original form data